# 2D array - compare three elements with if-statement

Tags: c++, arrays

I don't unerstand why the word foobar will not be printed.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a = 1;
    int b = 1;
    int c = 1;
    if(a==b==c)
        cout << "this line will be printed out ...\n";

    char ac = 'z';
    char bc = 'z';
    char cc = 'z';
    if(a==b==c)
        cout << "this line will be printed out ...\n";

    char array[3][3]={ {'a','a','a'},{'b','b','b'},{'c','c','c'} };
    if(array[0][0] == array[0][1] == array[0][2]) {
        // these lines will not be printed out
        cout << array[0][0] << array[0][1] << array[0][2] << "\n";
        cout << "foobar\n";
    }
    // aaa
    cout << array[0][0] << array[0][1] << array[0][2] << "\n";

}
```

I have tried something like this:
if(*(array[0]+0) == *(array[0]++1) == *(array[0]+2)  and so on
but this doesn't work too.

Thank you.

Comment: C++ isn’t Python, silly.

Comment: `a == b` evaluates to `bool`. This will be compared with `c`.

Comment: First line works because `true == 1`. Second works because you're comparing `a`, `b` and `c` again instead of `aa == bc == cc`.

Answer (score 4):

```
if(a==b==c)
```

That does not do what you think it does.  `a == b` will return `true` or `false`, which will then be compared to `c`.  If you want to compare multiple items, you need to do it like this:

```
if (a == b && b == c)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that

```
if(array[0][0] == array[0][1] == array[0][2])
```

You have to do this

```
if(array[0][0] == array[0][1] && array[0][1] == array[0][2])
```

I know the first one seems intuitive, but it doesn't do what you think it does. It first does

```
array[0][0] == array[0][1]
```

Which will return true, then it will compare array[0][2] == 1 (true), which will be false.

Comment: Technically, he *can* do `a == b == c`, but it will not do what he thinks it will.

Answer (score 0):

In the first if statement

```
if(a==b==c)
    cout << "this line will be printed out ...\n";
```

output is executed by the following reason. The equality operators are group from left to right.  The result of the comparison `a == b` is boolean value `true` Then this value is compared with c. It is converted to int value 1. As c is also equal to 1 then the statement with cout is executed.

In the secons if statement

```
if(array[0][0] == array[0][1] == array[0][2])
```

at first array[0][0] is compared with array[0][1]. As they are equal then the result of the comparision `array[0][0] == array[0][1]` is boolean true. Then this boolean value is compared with array[0][2]. Again the boolean value is converted to int value 1 and compared with 'a' (that is also promoted to int). As 1 is not equal to 'a' then the whole condition is false.

What you meant is the following

```
if( array[0][0] == array[0][1] && array[0][1] == array[0][2])
```

In this case the result of the condition will be equal to true because array[0][0] is equal to array[0][1] and array[0][1] is equal to array[0][2].

The condition in the first if statement also should be rewritten as

```
if(a==b && b==c)
```

then it will not depend on that c has value equal to 1.